# Can a regexp be used as a key in application.yaml in spring boot?

Tags: regex, spring-boot, yaml

```
kafka:
 topics:
   '.*testTopic': testValue
```

Is it possible to use regexp as a key in yaml file?
Especially I'm interested in spring boot application.yaml

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that spring boot remove `.*` even if it placed between single/double quotes. So, a regexp cannot be used as a key in application.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can.

```yaml
kafka:
 topics:
   [".*testTopic"]: testValue
```

And If there is a backslash in your regex you need to escape it with another `\`.